# How can I set up multihoming?

Tags: macos, osx-server, network, internet, ethernet

I am running Mac OS X Server 10.6 on my iMac and I am wondering how to multihome a Mac. I know it's possible to accomplish this by using both Wi-fi and Ethernet, but I just want to use Ethernet. Any idea how to set this up? Thanks.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve? Do you have two networks or two internet services that you wish to use?

Comment: Yes, I would like to run two websites on the server.

Comment: You can also use [name-based virtual sites](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) to avoid the need for multihoming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. All you have to do is add multiple Ethernet interfaces in Network Preferences. And then just configure each one to the correct settings and you're set to go. I tested this by hosting two different websites on two different IPs by multihoming my iMac and it worked!

- System Prefs -> Network dialog
- Press the `+` button and select the interface you want to add to (you may need to go back  and identify which one if you have multiple Ethernet ports).
- Name the service and press "Create"
- Configure the new service as you would a static (manual) interface
- Click "Apply"